# Accessing or Creating page from host web in app web

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, application-pages

I have created **SharePoint Hosted app**. I want to access page of **host web** in **app web**. Initially I have tried using `iframe` but got cross domain issue. Is there any possible solution to do this.

Comment: First provide Read permission to the app in Host Web. Then try using `SP.RequestExecutor.js` to resolve cross-domain issues

Comment: I have tried a lot. Do you have any working code